# Eigenvector Computation.

Tags: linear-algebra, algebra-precalculus, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, systems-of-equations

Two eigenvalue for $$A=
        \begin{pmatrix}
        .0144&.0117\\
        .0117&.0146\\
        \end{pmatrix}
$$
is  $\lambda_1=0.026200427$ and  $\lambda_2=0.002799573$.

I have computed the normalized eigenvector for $\lambda_1$. But for $\lambda_2$ I can't. Here is my attempt :

$$\mathbf A\mathbf x= \lambda_2 \mathbf x$$

$$ \begin{pmatrix}
        .0144&.0117\\
        .0117&.0146\\
        \end{pmatrix} \begin{pmatrix}
        x_1\\
        x_2\\
        \end{pmatrix}=0.002799573\begin{pmatrix}
        x_1\\
        x_2\\
        \end{pmatrix}$$

$$.0144 x_1+.0117 x_2=0.002799573 x_1$$
$$.0117 x_1+.0146 x_1=0.002799573 x_2$$

and after simplification  first equation yields ,

$$x_1=-0.948240875 x_2$$

and  second equation yields ,

$$x_1=-1.00858359 x_2.$$ This two equations don't match. Consequently arbitrarily choosing $x_2=1$ produces two different value of $x_1$.

Where am I doing mistake? I did it several times.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: [WolframAlpha](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=eig{{0.0144%2C+0.0117}%2C{0.0177%2C+0.0146}}) says that your eigenvalues are $0.028891$ and $0.000109031$, so that seems to be where your mistake is.

Comment: @Arthur No... , I use statistical software `R`. There I also checked the eigenvalues that I found manually. And both matched. Then I calculated eigenvector for $\lambda_1$, it also matched. But I get stumbled for eigenvector for $\lambda_2$.